# Issues with naming variables for zellers congruence project

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

i'm working on making a program in python that uses arrays since it's the new chapter i'm learning. The goal of my program will ask the user for month day and day and I seem to have it almost done except that i have an issue with 2 lines in this whole code. I will write a comment in where i'm getting the errors.

```
def calc_zellers_congruence(get_day: int, get_year: int, get_month: int) -> str:
    # Calculates the month day and year
    days = [""] * 7

    day_Of_Week = 0
    day_of_month = 0
    century = 0
    year_of_the_century = get_year % 100
    days[1] = "Sunday"
    days[2] = "Monday"
    days[3] = "Tuesday"
    days[4] = "Wednessday"
    days[5] = "Thursday"
    days[6] = "Friday"
    days[0] = "Saturday"
    dayOfWeek = day_of_month + 13 * get_month + int(1) / 5 + year_of_the_century + int(year_of_the_century) / 4 + int(
        century) / 4 + 5 * century % 7
    name_of_day = days[day_Of_Week]

    return name_of_day

def displayResults():
    print("Result" + day)

def get_day():
    print("Enter a Day")
    get_day = int(input())

    return get_day

def get_month():
    print("Enter a Month")
    month = int(input())

    return month

def get_year():
    print("Enter a Year")
    get_year: int(input())

    return year

# Main
# This program will calculate birthdays using arrays and zellers congruence
# References...Programming Fundamentals WiKi, J Robinson, GeeksForGeek.com
year = get_year()
month = get_month()
day = get_day()
calc_Zeller_Congruence: calc_zellers_congruence(get_year, get_month, get_day)
displayResults(calc_zellers_congruence)
```

I've tried renaming them but have gotten more errors after switching them from uppercase to lowercase and also adding snake cases.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Normally the prompt is put as the argument to `input()`, not a separate `print()` statement.

Comment: You have a typo: `get_year: int(input())` should be `year = int(input())`

Comment: You have the same problem on the line beginning with `calc_Zeller_Congruence:`. `:` is for type hints, `=` is for assignment.

Comment: And you have a colon instead of an equals on the penultimate line too. Find an editor with syntax highlighting